# Save data of input files multiple

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I'm trying to save the list of files in the post but it does not save the relationship.

I want to save the first post and then add the images inserted.

```php
class SaveData extends ComponentBase {
    public function onSubmitContact() {
        /*
         * This field: <input type="file" name="files[]" id='files' multiple="true"/>
         */
        $files = Input::file('files');

        $modelFiles = new MyModeToSave;
        $modelRelation = new ModelToRelation;

        foreach($files as $file):
            $modelFiles->data = $file;
            $modelFiles->save();
        endforeach;

        $modelRelation->title = post('title');
        /* more fields */
        $modelRelation->save();

        $modelRelation->files()->add($modelFiles);
    }
}
```

tanks
Code this is CMS OCTOBER

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your exact use case, but something like this should work:

```
    //Pass your model id, and then find it in your function
    $model = ModelToRelation::find(post('modelID'));
    //commit all the files relations
    $model->commitDeferred(post('_session_key'));

    foreach($model->files() as $file) {
        //now you can do stuff with the file...or model
    }
```